# Как изменить ключ активации в win 2000?

Tags: windows, активация

Утерян установочный диск с windows 2000 на старые машины остался только ключ активации,  как изменить ключ активации после установки с другого дистрибутива?

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь решение от майкрософт для Windows XP, возможно оно действует и для Windows 2000.

[Изменение ключа продукта, установленного по корпоративной лицензии](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328874/ru).